# Left rotate through carry in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to implement SHA1 in Ruby and in order to do so I need to preform a left rotate through carry. The code I've written seems to work for 1 rotation, but any more than that it fails my tests, anybody know why?

```
class Integer
  def rotate_left(count, size)
    temp = self

    count.times do
      first_bit = (self & 2 ** size)[size]
      temp = temp << 1
      temp = temp ^ first_bit
      temp = temp ^ (2 ** (size + 1))
    end

    return temp
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to add an example of your usage and what you expect.  When I do `5.rotate_left(2,2)` with the fixes mentioned below, I get 6.

Answer (score 2):

I checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_through_carry) first to make sure I understood the operation.  It looks as if you were losing your carry's.  Also, I added the test class to make sure I was getting the right answers.  I wasn't sure if you wanted to preserve the carried bits or not so I commented out the code to truncate the result.   Hope this helps!

```
class Integer
    def rotate_left(count, size)
        temp = self
        carry = 0

        count.times do
            temp = temp << 1
            temp = temp | carry
            carry = (temp >> size) & 1
        end

        return temp # & (( 1 << size ) - 1)
    end

end

if __FILE__ == $0 then

    require 'test/unit'

    class TestRotateLeft < Test::Unit::TestCase
        def test_no_rotation
            result = 5.rotate_left(0,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 5, result
            assert_equal 0, carry
        end

        def test_one_rotation
            result = 5.rotate_left(1,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 10, answer
            assert_equal 0, carry
        end

        def test_first_carry
            result = 5.rotate_left(2,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 4, answer
            assert_equal 1, carry
        end

        def test_shift_from_carry
            result = 5.rotate_left(3,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 9, answer
            assert_equal 0, carry
        end

        def test_second_carry
            result = 5.rotate_left(4,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 2, answer
            assert_equal 1, carry
        end

        def test_full_rotation
            result = 5.rotate_left(5,4)
            answer = result & 15
            carry = ( result & 16 ) >> 4
            assert_equal 5, answer
            assert_equal 0, carry
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: I think @J-_-L's answer is much simpler.  This version passes the tests above:

    def rotate_left(count=1, size=32)
        self << count | self >> ((size+1) - count)
    end

Answer (score 0):

what are you using for `size`?  If you are trying to do a 4 bit rotation for example, and you set size to 4, then the first_bit calculation is getting the 5th bit:

```
 2**4 => 16
 16.to_s(2) => "10000"
```

---

So the indexing is Ok.  But in the inner loop, you are getting first_bit from  `self` instead of temp.  So this will only work the 1st time through.

Comment: I was passing in a 0 based size.

Comment: Wow, not sure how I missed that, thanks. That does fix 1 issue, however if I pass in 5 => 101, it will do the first rotation and end up with 011, which it then truncates to 11 and I can't do any more rotations correctly.

Comment: is it possible it is using `Integer#size` instead of the `size` parameter?  Try renaming the parameter to `bits` or something like that...

Comment: Wouldn't Integer#size always return 8 for a fixnum?

Comment: Also the `temp = temp ^ (2 ** (size + 1))` only works to clear the high bit if the high bit is set.  Otherwise it sets the high bit.  The more common way to do this is `temp = temp&((2**(size+1))-1)`.   *And the more common way to write `2**n` when you are doing bitwise operations is `1<<n`*

Comment: Integer#size returns 4 on my machine, which is 4 bytes, not 4 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented [SHA-256 in Ruby](https://rbjl.janlelis.com/17/sha-256) (which is using right rotate) and finally used this code:

```
class Integer
  def rotate(n=1)
    self >> n | self << (32 - n)
  end
end
```

You can modify it for left rotate:

```
class Integer
  def lotate(n=1)
    self << n | self >> (32 - n)
  end
end
```

Although it's very hard to understand... it works :)

Comment: Don't you need a mask to get rid of the high bits on the left shift?  Otherwise you are doing a multiply. And Ruby won't truncate on overflow, it will just return a Bignum.

Comment: Hm, I am not 100% sure... I had to cut off the high bits anyway later in the code.